# Difficulty Displaying a Users Name after Logging them in for Nodejs App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on making a Nodejs application and was able to successfully allow a user to register, store their information in a `MongoDB` database, and allow them to login. However, I am having trouble getting the user's name to display on every page after they login. To my understanding, I should use something like so:

```
res.render("./home/about", {
        name: req.user.name
    });
```

I do however have to have the user logged in to be able to grab that name, otherwise, it will error. I was wondering if there was a workaround to this so I am able to display the username on every page?
This is the link to my git repository: [Github llink](https://github.com/halsheik/RecipeWarehouse.git)

I would appreciate any help.

***Note*** I currently do not have the html code where I would display the users name and have removed the chunk of code displayed above.

Image showing added code: [image: Click Here]

Shows I have access to users name on about page but not home page.

SOLVED:

By placing the following code in my app.js file:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});
```

I was able to attain access to all data attached to the user object. In order to check if it is valid, I would do the following:

```
<% if(user){ %>
      <a>Welcome, <%= user.name %>!</a>
<% } %>
```

***NOTE*** The '<% %>' are 'ejs' tags that allow me to use javascript within my HTML code.

Comment: `I do however have to have the user logged in to be able to grab that name, otherwise, it will error.` -- So what you're saying is that the username is accessible when logged in but you want to access it when you aren't or?

Comment: I am saying that the users name is accessible when logged in, however, I cannot display on all pages (i.e. homepage, about page, etc.). This is because I send the users name (or have access to it after they log in) by putting this code under where I render set pages:

res.render("./home/about", {
        name: req.user.name
    });
 
I cannot however place it under each page I render in because it will give me an error since I don’t have access to req.user.name unless the users logged in.

Comment: So the username is accessible only on which page exactly when the user is logged in?

Comment: On pages I protect from user access unless logged in and I send the users name to by using this { name: req.user.name }. So, for my example, I protected the about page and sent the name to get it to work. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: I added a picture depicting this user the 'note' in the post above.

Comment: router.get("/", ensureAuth, (req, res, next) => { 
      res.render(""./home/about"", {
        layout: "your_layout",
        data: data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});

Comment: How to Pass Data Between Routes in Express did not answer my question, thank you though.

Comment: I have tried to use the code you shared Hamada but it does not seem to work. I have tried to debug, but to no avail, I was not able to get it to work.

Comment: @HossamAlsheikh Can you please post the solution you found as an answer here so it can help future readers who might have the same issue too.

Comment: I did, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing the following code in my app.js file:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});
```

I was able to attain access to all data attached to the user object. In order to check if it is valid, I would do the following:

```
<% if(user){ %>
      <a>Welcome, <%= user.name %>!</a>
<% } %>
```

***NOTE*** The '<% %>' are 'ejs' tags that allow me to use javascript within my HTML code.